# Convert entity to custom format

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a model that I convert to JSON. To reduce the amount of data, I replace any parent entities with the id. Previously I did it like this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(from program in context.Programs select new {
  id = program.id,
  name = program.name,
  parent_id = program.parent.id
});
```

But since I need to do this at multiple places, I added a `ToJSON` function to my model:

```
public class ProgramModel
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int? id { get; set; }

    [Required, Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public virtual ParentModel parent { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(128)]
    public string name { get; set; }

    public object ToJSON()
    {
        return new
        {
            id = id,
            name = name,
            parent_id = parent.id
        };
    }
}
```

Then I use it like this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(from program in context.Programs select program.ToJSON());
```

Which does not work, bringing me to my question. How can I do something like above in a way that avoids code duplication?

The exception thrown at the above line:

> System.NotSupportedException : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object ToJSON()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use only LINQ, remember good ol' `foreach`:

```
List<object> objs = new List<object>();

foreach (var program in context.Programs)
{
    objs.Add(program.ToJSON());
}

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(from program in objs select program);
```

Comment: But wouldn't this fetch the entire entity including all parents?

Comment: With the normal query you are also fetching all the entities.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

add "`using System.Web.Script.Serialization;`" namespace

Then in Entity class

```
public class ProgramModel
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int? id { get; set; }

        [Required, Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public virtual ParentModel parent { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(128)]
        public string name { get; set; }

        public object ToJSON()
        {

                JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(this);
                return sJSON;
                //id = id,
                //name = name,
                //parent_id = parent.id

        }
    }
```

To test try this in Page_Load()

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ParentModel prmodel = new ParentModel();
                prmodel.id = 5;
                List<ProgramModel> listdata = new List<ProgramModel>();
                ProgramModel data = new ProgramModel();

                data.id = 7;
                data.parent = prmodel;
                data.name = "program";
                listdata.Add(data);

                var jsdata = from program in listdata select program.ToJSON();

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception is because the Linq-Entites cannot transalte the ToJSON() method to a sql command

You can try this

```
   //first get all the items using Linq-Entities
     var programs = (from program in context.Programs select program).ToList();

     //use foreach on the list
     programs.ForEach(program =>
            {
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(program.ToJSON());
            });
```